# How to put GP object with effect between two fills in another GP object without effect layering incorrectly

Tags: grease-pencil

I need to have a Grease Pencil object with a blur effect rendered between strokes of another GP object. To do this, I am using 3D Location for Stroke Depth Order and Stroke and Layer Offset modifiers to offset the stroke locations so that I can put the effect object between them. The problem is that the blur effect won't render as expected. It will only act as if it is above both strokes or below both. I made the following simplified example to illustrate the issue. The purple and blue shapes are part of the same object that I want to sandwich the green shape.

If the effect object origin position is behind the other object, this happens:
[image]
If it is in front, then this happens:
[image]
Is there a way to have the interaction with the purple shape in the first image and the interaction with the blue shape in the second image?

I could probably do it by separating the blue and purple into different objects, but in my actual use case this would over-complicate things a lot and I would really prefer to keep it all in one object.